# Cannot convert video using CarrierWave / Voyeur

Tags: video, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2, carrierwave

I'm trying to use Voyeur gem to convert video from .mp4 to .webm then upload it. Here is my code:
app/uploads/video_uploader.rb

`class VideoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::VideoConverter
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
  version :mp4 do
    process :encode_video => [:mp4]
    def full_filename(for_file)
      "#{File.basename(for_file, File.extname(for_file))}.mp4"
    end
  end
  version :webm do
    process :encode_video => [:webm]
    def full_filename(for_file)
      "#{File.basename(for_file, File.extname(for_file))}.webm"
    end
  end
end`

video_converter.rb module has been placed in /lib/carrierwave/processing/

`autoload :VideoConverter, 'carrierwave/processing/video_converter'` has been added in /lib/carrierwave.rb

My model:

`class Uploader < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'Voyeur'
  attr_accessible :user_id,:attach_file
  belongs_to :user
  mount_uploader :attach_file, VideoUploader
end`

But I can't upload video, the console raise error:
`Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - ffmpeg -i /home/------/______/public/uploads/tmp/20121211-0943-7368-8271/tmpfile`

Is there any suggestion?

The most simple command I use in console : `Voyeur::Media.new( filename: path_to_file ).convert( to: :mp4 )` still fail with similar error.

Answer (score 0):

My process to get these two gems to work together was a little different and maybe it will help others in the same situation.

Step 1.) Follow the directions on both carrierwave and voyeur github.

- https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave
- https://github.com/devthenet/voyeur

Step 2.)install ffmpeg and its dependencies. I was doing this on ubuntu and was getting the error no such file or directory until I followed [this](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide) install

Step 3.) this [website](http://trackingrails.com/posts/video-encoding-processor-for-carrierwave) is older and has a few things that need to be changed.

- put the video_converter.rb file in the directory carrierwave-0.8.0/lib/carrierwave/processing
- change line 22 in this file from

  ```
  Voyeur::Video.new( filename: tmp_path ).convert( to: format.to_sym, output_filename: current_path )
  ```

  to

  ```
  Voyeur::Media.new( filename: tmp_path ).convert( to: format.to_sym, output_filename: current_path )
  ```

  add the following line to carrierwave-0.8.0/lib/carrierwave/processing.rb

  ```
  require "carrierwave/processing/video_converter"
  ```
- in the uploader directory that you created for carrierwave edit your app/uploaders/avatar_uploader.rb file to match video_uploader.rb

Hope this helps